# Foolproof way to do configuration #define/#ifdef

Tags: c++, c

I'm working with a moderately sized embedded C++ project that has a number of configurations for different target products. There are a good number of macros that get set for various configuration items in the different configurations and I'm trying to make that system as error-proof as possible.

Initially, I was just doing the standard thing:

```
#define CFG_FOO
    
#ifdef CFG_FOO
<code here>
#endif
```

but I'm always afraid I'm going to mistype a macro name in an ifdef and have a hard to find bug, because this evaluates to false without error:

```
#ifdef CFG_FOOO
```

So, I changed all the macros to this format, which requires that the macro in question be defined, defining all the ones that I want to evaluate as false to 0:

```
#define CFG_FOO() (1)
#define CFG_BAR() (0)

#if CFG_FOO()
<code is active>
#endif

#if CFG_BAR()
<code is inactive>
#endif

// Produces error, as desired:
#ifdef CFG_FOOO()
#endif
```

This was good, *except* that then if I accidentally enter the following (which I found I do all the time, just out of habit) it is true and the contained code is compiled:

```
#ifdef CFG_BAR
<this is active>
#endif
```

So I'm looking for a solution that:

1. Always generates an error for mistyped CFG_xxx item.
2. Doesn't allow for unintended consequences if using the wrong directive #if vs. #ifdef (it's fine if there's a error for "incorrect" usage.)
3. Doesn't require additional libraries/frameworks (like Boost).
4. Doesn't require an additional tool to process all the code (this is what I'm doing now, scanning for *any* #ifdef and generating an error, but that's not ideal.)
5. Actually removes the unneeded code. A runtime solution is probably impractical as the code size needs to be tightly controlled.

NOTE: I'm aware of the -Wundef option for gcc, but I don't believe that really helps, as the accidental #ifdef situation is still present.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  If C++, and you can use C++17, then a lot of this can be avoided by using `if constexpr`.

Comment: checking for specific values rather than only whether the symbol is defined is less supectible to typos

Comment: It cannot be foolproof; fools will always find a way to abuse the pre-processor.

Comment: alt. restructure your code to minimize ifdefs and instead put ifdefed code into libraries. In my experience - especially when a lot of coders are involved - ifdefs  can easily become a real mess after a couple of years, making it really difficult to see if the right code was included or not in the binary.

Comment: Use an IDE that auto-completes.

Comment: [i]Use an IDE that auto-completes[/i]  I think this is the solution. I checked and I set up Emacs to do code completion years ago but, for some reason, never used it. I suspect that I'll now use that constantly for other non-macro-related purposes as well.  Good stuff in the other answers as well; a lot to think about.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of repeatedly do

```
#if CFG_FOO()
<code is active>
#endif
```

since C99 or C++11, you might have once (per config)

```
#if CFG_FOO() // or #ifdef CFG_FOO
# define WITH_FOO(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
# define WITH_FOO(...) /*Empty*/
#endif
```

And then

```
WITH_FOO(
<code is active>
)
```

Note:

- It might probably break auto-indentation.
- Not sure it is better than traditional way more prone to typo.

Comment: This will, for sure, mess with nice IDE highlighting and all.

Answer (score 3):

My best recommendation is never get yourself into a situation where `CFG_FOO` is valid, `CFG_BAR` is valid, but both together is not valid.

We can do better by simply avoiding this problem. Specialized form for a switch ladder. `CFG` is a bad prefix but I'm assuming it's an artifact of minimalization and you simply will have a better one.

modeswitch.h:

```
#define CFGMODE_FOO 1
#define CFGMODE_BAR 2
```

header.h:

```
#if CFG == CFGMODE_FOO
#elif CFG == CFGMODE_BAR
#else
#error CFG has unsupported value
#endif
```

program.c

```
#include "modeswitch.h"
#define CFG CFGMODE_FOO
#include "header.h"
```

If I read this wrong and you're not using this stuff in `.h` files than I wonder why you have both C and C++ tags but just inline the stuff and it will still work.

My understanding is there's enough power in `##` that there's a way to get rid of the pre-header but it's so hard that it doesn't meet any reasonable definition of foolproof.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the gcc compiler, it has a built-in #pragma for this, that throws a compiler error anytime a variable/phrase is used. This would mostly be used when you want to prevent future programmers from using things like PRINTF statements, but you can also use it in a clunkier way to eliminate the possibility that you mistype your variable names in a common way. ie. you would type something like:

```
#pragma GCC poison CFG_FOOO CFG_FOOD CFG_FOO0 CFG_FO
```

Note - I've only ever worked with this in theory, so I'm not certain it will work for you. Slightly more info in this doc:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html